# Powershell: GUI to validate input

Tags: powershell, user-interface

How can I easily validate some variables calculated within a Power shell script?

Let's assume, I have the following result of a script:

```
$hashtable = @{1="one";2="two";3="three"}
```

I further know, that with Out-GridView and -PassThru, I can display these record in a table and can return those values, which have been selected.

Moreover, I know, that with New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, I can add an textbox, with which the user can specify an input.

My problem is now, that it can happen, that the result differs from the real result. So, e.g., for the key '2', the correct result would be "four" and not "two".

How can I combine the Out-GridView with the TextBox, so that the result is visualized in a nice manner and the user can verify that result via the TextBoxes?

If that is not possible, exists there another way to correct wrong entries within the map using a simple GUI?`

Comment: Are you saying that you want to order your results by number, but in word form?

Comment: No - I want to display that result in a table, but want to be able to change the values of the second column.
So, in the table we have the row ID = 2, Value = "two" and (the idea is) an additional column defined as a textfield, where you can change the value of the column "value".

Comment: Oh, I would personally display it as a dataview object with an extra column. Then have a `Submit` button (or whatever name you want to give it). Then in the OnClick event handler for the button have it iterate the rows and change the value in the underlying data structure wherever there is a value in the extra field.

Comment: But what is the advantage of using a dataview here? You still need to use Out-GridView to visualize it, don't you?

Comment: Well, to use a button in the first place you would need to create a WinForm to contain the button. On that form you would display the data with a dataview instead of using Out-Gridview.